# Minecraft Keeps crashing when fullscreened on server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

In single player Minecraft, I like to get the full experience and I hit `F11` to go full screen as soon as I log in.

But unfortunately when I did this on multi-player the game crashed unless I waited at least half a minute after joining.

And with the recent update single player now emulates a server, so the crashing happens on single player too!

Is there any way to stop this happening?

Comment: Did you try going to fullscreen before connecting?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post this as a real answer then, since otherwise this question will still show up as unanswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues when trying this. However you can switch to fullscreen before connecting while still in the menu. This reduced the amounts of crashes for me to "rarely".