# Turning fullscreen on made Minecraft crash, and now it crashes on start every time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I switched to full screen on minecraft, the screen turned black as if it were loading it took a while so i closed minecraft and reopened it. When I logged on it gave me a program on my taskbar saying "minecraft minecraft" then when i closed the program it gave me this error message:

```
java(tm) platform SE binary has stopped working.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have to full-screen? Why not just maximize? It's pretty much the same effect.

Comment: i was gonna see what the difference was between full screen and maximizing it

Comment: It sounds like the difference is: full screen doesn't work.

Comment: So are you able to play, or is this preventing minecraft from running? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: I am not able to play minecraft

Comment: Why are you not able to play Minecraft? What does full-screen have to do with Minecraft not starting? Also, it would be nice if you could give us some error logs.

Comment: ok so, at the beginning i went to full screen (f11) that is when it crashed. From there, when i try to login minecraft as i said it gives me a new program. When i shut it, it shuts minecraft as well and i have no idea what a error log is. Tell me what it is then i might be able to tell you

Comment: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/903148-getting-and-identifying-error-logs/

Comment: So closing this second program closes minecraft as well… What does minecraft do if you *don't* close the second program?

Comment: This "second program" is just a message from Java. Java is always running when you're playing Minecraft, it just doesn't show in the active windows unless there is a problem.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79492/minecraft-keeps-crashing-when-fullscreened-on-server

Answer (score 8):

Try turning off full-screen manually:

1. Open the start menu in Windows and, in the search bar, enter 'Minecraft'.  Look for the '.minecraft' directory in the search results.
2. Find the 'options' file; it should have items on each line, such as `Clouds:False` and `graphics: fancy`.
3. Find the line labeled `fullscreen`.  If the value to the right of the colon says `true`, replace it with `false`.  Save and close the file.
4. Try running Minecraft again.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for instruction on how not start Minecraft in full screen mode

Comment: @YiJiang Actually, this might actually be the solution. The OP was only trying fullscreen out of curiosity—their actual problem is it broke the game. Toggling fullscreen off in the config may well allow them to play (in a window) again at all.