# How can I exit fullscreen in Minecraft and it stays on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just downloaded it and I accidently pressed fullscreen. Now all I see is a back screen in front of me. I tried all commands and stuff, but only the quit command works. I want to exit full screen but not actually exit out of Minecraft, just the fullscreen.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Arqade.  Searching for [Minecraft] fullscreen finds this is already answered at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97289/turning-fullscreen-on-made-minecraft-crash-and-now-it-crashes-on-start-every-ti -- please search before posting a question.

Comment: just press F11.

Answer (score 2):

Press F11 :-), this is the toggle for full screen