# Minecraft crashes when I go into full screen. What do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

This is happening in all versions of minecraft, modded and unmodded.

### Here is some stuff:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005a09fa48, pid=4984, tid=4692

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x3fa48]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000225e800):  JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4692, stack(0x00000000023d0000,0x00000000024d0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000000000001b8

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000005c246700, RCX=0x000000005f1949a0, RDX=0x000000005b070090
RSP=0x00000000024ce9c0, RBP=0x000000005b070090, RSI=0x00000000004652e0, RDI=0x000000005c2d67b0
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x000000005b070090, R10=0x00000000003ea450, R11=0x000000005a7bbd40
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x000007fef86e4d70, R14=0x0000000000001254, R15=0x000007fef87b04d0
RIP=0x000000005a09fa48, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000024ce9c0)
0x00000000024ce9c0:   000000005c2d67b0 000000005c246700
0x00000000024ce9d0:   000000005c246700 0000000000000000
0x00000000024ce9e0:   fffffffffffffffe 0000000077601ac5
0x00000000024ce9f0:   00000000001102b2 fffffffffa010ae7
0x00000000024cea00:   000000005c2d67b0 000000005a322aeb
0x00000000024cea10:   000000005c246700 00000000003fd6c0
0x00000000024cea20:   000000005b070090 000007fef86c0000
0x00000000024cea30:   00000000024cea48 0000000000000000
0x00000000024cea40:   0000000000000000 00000000024cea48
0x00000000024cea50:   00000000024cea48 0000000000000001
0x00000000024cea60:   00000000003b5238 000007fffffd5000
0x00000000024cea70:   000000000074616d 000000000225e800
0x00000000024cea80:   00000000024cecc8 0000000000000000
0x00000000024cea90:   fffffffffa010ae7 0000000059dab7e0
0x00000000024ceaa0:   00000000737e266c 0000000000010000
0x00000000024ceab0:   000000000225e800 00000000024cecc8 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000005a09fa48)
0x000000005a09fa28:   8d f8 b6 00 00 44 8b 86 a8 01 00 00 ba 40 8d 00
0x000000005a09fa38:   00 48 8b cd e8 ff e9 00 00 4c 8b 85 f8 b6 00 00
0x000000005a09fa48:   41 ff 88 b8 01 00 00 41 83 b8 b8 01 00 00 00 75
0x000000005a09fa58:   15 49 8b 88 b0 01 00 00 48 85 c9 74 09 48 8b 01 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000005c246700 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000005f1949a0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000005b070090 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000024ce9c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000225e800
RBP=0x000000005b070090 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000000004652e0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000005c2d67b0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000005b070090 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000003ea450 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000005a7bbd40 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R13=0x000007fef86e4d70 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000001254 is an unknown value
R15=0x000007fef87b04d0 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00000000023d0000,0x00000000024d0000],  sp=0x00000000024ce9c0,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x3fa48]
C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x2c2aeb]
C  [OPENGL32.dll+0x2517e]
C  [OPENGL32.dll+0x25604]
C  [lwjgl64.dll+0xe131]
C  0x00000000027b3874

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nMakeCurrent(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.makeCurrent(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PeerInfo;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V+7
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.makeCurrent()V+46
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.makeCurrent()V+14
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.makeCurrent()V+3
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.makeCurrentAndSetSwapInterval()V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setDisplayMode(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/DisplayMode;)V+70
j  beq.au()V+233
j  beq.r()V+35
j  beq.W()V+84
j  bhm.l()V+34
j  bhm.p()V+32
j  beq.t()V+243
j  beq.av()V+177
j  beq.a()V+74
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1094
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000058869000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=2908, stack(0x0000000067430000,0x0000000067530000)]
  0x0000000057646000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4908, stack(0x0000000067300000,0x0000000067400000)]
  0x00000000574aa800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3268, stack(0x00000000670e0000,0x00000000671e0000)]
  0x000000005f8d4800 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1564, stack(0x00000000671f0000,0x00000000672f0000)]
  0x0000000058f27000 JavaThread "LWJGL Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4788, stack(0x0000000066770000,0x0000000066870000)]
  0x000000005f8d6800 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3292, stack(0x000000005f480000,0x000000005f580000)]
  0x00000000570bd800 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5112, stack(0x0000000060570000,0x0000000060670000)]
  0x0000000058bc4800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3988, stack(0x0000000059e60000,0x0000000059f60000)]
  0x0000000058d78800 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3056, stack(0x0000000059b60000,0x0000000059c60000)]
  0x0000000057789800 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2396, stack(0x0000000058370000,0x0000000058470000)]
  0x0000000055f7f000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2368, stack(0x0000000056d60000,0x0000000056e60000)]
  0x0000000055f7e000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2968, stack(0x0000000056a80000,0x0000000056b80000)]
  0x0000000055f2c800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3616, stack(0x00000000562f0000,0x00000000563f0000)]
  0x0000000055f28800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3992, stack(0x00000000568c0000,0x00000000569c0000)]
  0x0000000055f27800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2540, stack(0x00000000567b0000,0x00000000568b0000)]
  0x0000000055f26800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1536, stack(0x0000000056620000,0x0000000056720000)]
  0x0000000055ec9800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4928, stack(0x0000000056490000,0x0000000056590000)]
  0x0000000055ec2000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4460, stack(0x00000000561e0000,0x00000000562e0000)]
=>0x000000000225e800 JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=4692, stack(0x00000000023d0000,0x00000000024d0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000055eb8000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000056070000,0x0000000056170000] [id=4484]
  0x0000000056e61000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000057330000,0x0000000057430000] [id=3508]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 58831K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,  44% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2df4f70, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  90% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7ebede0, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 68063K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 31253K, capacity 31455K, committed 31860K, reserved 1077248K
  class space    used 3906K, capacity 3984K, committed 4016K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011fd0000,0x00000000121e0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000119d0000

Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0x0000000002150f18
 Bits: [0x00000000123b0000, 0x00000000131b0000)

Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0x0000000002150fd8
 Bits: [0x0000000000250000, 0x0000000000288000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000220000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=10349Kb max_used=10460Kb free=235410Kb
 bounds [0x00000000027a0000, 0x00000000031f0000, 0x00000000117a0000]
 total_blobs=3923 nmethods=3192 adapters=645
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 19.620 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 4083       3       bfg::c (14 bytes)
Event: 19.620 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 nmethod 4083 0x0000000002d902d0 code [0x0000000002d90440, 0x0000000002d90668]
Event: 19.688 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 4084       3       java.nio.HeapByteBuffer::put (167 bytes)
Event: 19.689 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 nmethod 4084 0x0000000002b1a1d0 code [0x0000000002b1a440, 0x0000000002b1b758]
Event: 19.898 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 4085       3       java.lang.Boolean::parseBoolean (19 bytes)
Event: 19.898 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 nmethod 4085 0x0000000002f74590 code [0x0000000002f74700, 0x0000000002f74988]
Event: 19.901 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 4086       3       org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay::handleMessage (29 bytes)
Event: 19.901 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 nmethod 4086 0x0000000002a35410 code [0x0000000002a35580, 0x0000000002a35798]
Event: 19.901 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 4087       3       org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay::doHandleMessage (929 bytes)
Event: 19.907 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 nmethod 4087 0x0000000002c707d0 code [0x0000000002c70be0, 0x0000000002c72a68]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 9.124 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 114500K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  73% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6fd1278, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 48462K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 25654K, capacity 25775K, committed 26100K, reserved 1073152K
  class space    used 3251K, capacity 3294K, committed 3376K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 9.141 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 6930K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  53% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7a04948, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 51071K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 25654K, capacity 25775K, committed 26100K, reserved 1073152K
  class space    used 3251K, capacity 3294K, committed 3376K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 10.790 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 111890K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  53% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7a04948, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 51071K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 25800K, capacity 25935K, committed 26100K, reserved 1073152K
  class space    used 3257K, capacity 3326K, committed 3376K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 10.801 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 8154K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  62% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6e76b00, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 51071K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 25800K, capacity 25935K, committed 26100K, reserved 1073152K
  class space    used 3257K, capacity 3326K, committed 3376K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 11.825 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 113114K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  62% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6e76b00, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 44917K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 26097K, capacity 26253K, committed 26612K, reserved 1073152K
  class space    used 3276K, capacity 3325K, committed 3376K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 11.842 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 11846K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  90% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7ed1ad8, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 44917K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 26097K, capacity 26253K, committed 26612K, reserved 1073152K
  class space    used 3276K, capacity 3325K, committed 3376K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 14.460 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 108411K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,  92% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c5e4d300, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  90% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7ed1ad8, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 44917K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 29799K, capacity 30059K, committed 30452K, reserved 1075200K
  class space    used 3745K, capacity 3820K, committed 3888K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 14.532 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=10 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 54945K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 29799K, capacity 30059K, committed 30452K, reserved 1075200K
  class space    used 3745K, capacity 3820K, committed 3888K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 14.835 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=10 (full 3):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 115351K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,  97% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c63e5db0, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 54945K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 29823K, capacity 30059K, committed 30452K, reserved 1075200K
  class space    used 3745K, capacity 3820K, committed 3888K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 14.873 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=11 (full 3):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 11771K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000c8000000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c6680000)
  from space 13056K,  90% used [0x00000000c7340000, 0x00000000c7ebede0, 0x00000000c8000000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c6680000, 0x00000000c7340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 122880K, used 68063K [0x00000000c8000000, 0x00000000cf800000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 29823K, capacity 30059K, committed 30452K, reserved 1075200K
  class space    used 3745K, capacity 3820K, committed 3888K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 14.172 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=unreached action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002a7234c method=java.util.HashMap.entrySet()Ljava/util/Set; @ 6
Event: 14.222 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002cb2e18 method=java.util.regex.Matcher.match(II)Z @ 86
Event: 14.297 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002d188a0 method=java.util.regex.Matcher.search(I)Z @ 86
Event: 14.297 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002f87bfc method=java.util.regex.Matcher.search(I)Z @ 86
Event: 15.142 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a36b08 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 50
Event: 15.142 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a36b08 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 50
Event: 15.142 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a36b08 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 50
Event: 15.142 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002a36b08 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 50
Event: 15.217 Thread 0x00000000634f8000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002bced70 method=sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineUpdate([BII)V @ 128
Event: 17.308 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unreached action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002b10448 method=java.net.URL.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/net/URLStreamHandler;)V @ 30

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 18.588 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1110b10) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 18.589 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c11247d0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 18.589 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1127068) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 18.590 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c112ba78) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 18.591 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1135da0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 19.753 Thread 0x00000000570bd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException': sleep interrupted> (0x00000000c1dca1c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 3141]
Event: 19.753 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1153c58) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 19.819 Thread 0x00000000570bd800 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException': sleep interrupted> (0x00000000c1dca3c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 3141]
Event: 19.821 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1159ea0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 19.887 Thread 0x000000000225e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000c1165498) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]

Events (10 events):
Event: 19.155 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002f7a410
Event: 19.155 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002f897d0
Event: 19.155 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002fb4550
Event: 19.620 Thread 0x0000000055f7e000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000002fddbd0
Event: 19.753 loading class com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedSet
Event: 19.753 loading class com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedSet done
Event: 19.821 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/WindowsKeycodes
Event: 19.821 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/WindowsKeycodes done
Event: 19.887 loading class bic
Event: 19.887 loading class bic done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f900000 - 0x000000013f934000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
0x00000000775e0000 - 0x000000007778a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000773c0000 - 0x00000000774df000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd670000 - 0x000007fefd6db000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007feff340000 - 0x000007feff41b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefefb0000 - 0x000007feff04f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefdd10000 - 0x000007fefdd2f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefee80000 - 0x000007fefefad000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000774e0000 - 0x00000000775da000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefdb90000 - 0x000007fefdbf7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefedd0000 - 0x000007fefedde000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff820000 - 0x000007feff8ea000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefba00000 - 0x000007fefbbf4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefede0000 - 0x000007fefee51000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feff050000 - 0x000007feff07e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefdc00000 - 0x000007fefdd09000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000074730000 - 0x0000000074802000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000073ed0000 - 0x000000007472a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef80b0000 - 0x000007fef80b9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007feff080000 - 0x000007feff0cd000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefd720000 - 0x000007fefd728000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefb310000 - 0x000007fefb34b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x00000000777a0000 - 0x00000000777a7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000075000000 - 0x000000007500f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000074950000 - 0x0000000074978000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\java.dll
0x0000000073eb0000 - 0x0000000073ec6000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefddb0000 - 0x000007fefeb3a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff130000 - 0x000007feff333000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd360000 - 0x000007fefd36f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000073ea0000 - 0x0000000073ead000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\management.dll
0x0000000073e80000 - 0x0000000073e9a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefcac0000 - 0x000007fefcb15000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefce90000 - 0x000007fefce97000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x0000000073e60000 - 0x0000000073e71000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\nio.dll
0x000007fefb780000 - 0x000007fefb795000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef89a0000 - 0x000007fef89b5000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef8980000 - 0x000007fef8999000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefc950000 - 0x000007fefc9ab000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef8970000 - 0x000007fef897b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefc620000 - 0x000007fefc627000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefb060000 - 0x000007fefb087000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefb090000 - 0x000007fefb09b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef8f30000 - 0x000007fef8f38000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefaf40000 - 0x000007fefaf93000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180053000     C:\Users\Alex Dilko\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11\1.11-natives-105613514104171\lwjgl64.dll
0x000007fef86c0000 - 0x000007fef87dd000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x000007fef8df0000 - 0x000007fef8e1d000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007fef6f10000 - 0x000007fef7001000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fefae10000 - 0x000007fefae18000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007feff420000 - 0x000007feff5f7000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefd6e0000 - 0x000007fefd716000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007feff600000 - 0x000007feff6d8000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefd580000 - 0x000007fefd59a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefabf0000 - 0x000007fefac08000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefc610000 - 0x000007fefc61c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefcfc0000 - 0x000007fefcfd8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc830000 - 0x000007fefc877000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd510000 - 0x000007fefd52e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd200000 - 0x000007fefd20f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefaec0000 - 0x000007fefaed1000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefae60000 - 0x000007fefae78000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000073330000 - 0x00000000734c8000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefb920000 - 0x000007fefb976000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000000005a060000 - 0x000000005a833000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4icd64.dll
0x000000005a940000 - 0x000000005ae9b000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4dev64.dll
0x000007fef2940000 - 0x000007fef29dc000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x000007fef8670000 - 0x000007fef86b2000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x00000000021f0000 - 0x0000000002228000     C:\Users\Alex Dilko\AppData\Local\Temp\jna\jna6972864920859841984.dll
0x0000000002260000 - 0x00000000022c4000 

[...]
```

I ran out of space: http://pastebin.com/sU4PJdsb. I'm running on Windows 7.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?

Comment: Did you try this: [Turning fullscreen on made Minecraft crash, and now it crashes on start every time](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97289/turning-fullscreen-on-made-minecraft-crash-and-now-it-crashes-on-start-every-ti)

Comment: I think this is a question for SuperUser. A crash is not specific to games and the way to analyze it is similar to other programs. In your case, the information is quite useless, because the crash happens outside of Java and the relevant information is not included because "Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows". Run it again with `-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash` to get that information, then post it on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your video card's driver.

The error report said:

"Problematic frame:
 C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x3fa48]"

ig4icd6464 is driver for your video card. ig4icd64= Intel Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows 7.
So, that makes the problem most likely that this driver is out of date.

Good luck ¯_(ツ)_/¯